# Guarantee symmetric, positive definite matrix within cost function

Tags: optimization, matrix-decomposition

Let's say I want to calculate the positive definite, symmetric matrix $\Sigma$ by optimizing the cost function $f$ with

$$
min(f(\Sigma))
$$

In a optimization regular solver I would define the elements of the upper triangle of $\Sigma$ as the variables that are supposed to be optimized in order to get a symmetric $\Sigma$. However, additionally to symmetry, I also want it to be positive definite. This is difficult to formulate, as many solvers allow a boundary for the optimization variables, but not any arbitrary feasibility function.

So I have the idea to not optimize the elements of $\Sigma$ directly, but to consider

$$
\Sigma = Q \cdot \Lambda \cdot Q^T
$$

where $Q$ is the matrix of eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices) and to optimize the non-zero elements in $Q$ and $\Lambda$.

Now I can place the formulate for the solver that the elements in $\Lambda$ are supposed to be larger than 0.  From my understanding gathered from the Cholesky decomposition, this fact that I am using $Q$ with $Q^T$ already guarantees symmetry, so I do not further need to consider this. Using the above formula I can replace each occurrence of $\Sigma$ in $f$ with $Q \cdot \Lambda \cdot Q^T$.

Only caveat is that I now have more variables that need to be optimized than before because if $\Sigma$ has the size of $n \times n$, I previously had $(n^2+n)/2$ optimization variables, but now I have $n^2 + n$ optimization variables.

I tried to find out as much as possible before asking and get the impression I already solved all my questions myself - however I am not sure whether I did a mistake in my reasoning, so my question left is: Am I right or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Why not introduce the constraint $\Sigma \succeq 0$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: This restricts the number of allowed $\Sigma$ substantially. Also, are you sure this guarantees $\Sigma$ to be positive definite?

Comment: I wrote $\Sigma \succeq 0$, not $\Sigma \geq 0$. Looks like you're not familiar with the notation.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Ah, sorry. $\Sigma\succeq0$ means that $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite and $\Sigma\ge0$ means all elements of $\Sigma$ are non-negative, do I get this right? If not, please state what you mean. If I got you right now, then I don't see what you point is, since I explained that many solvers only except boundaries on the optimization variables and guaranteeing positive definiteness can not directly expressed as a boundary.

Comment: Semidefinite programming (SDP) is based on PSD constraints. If you can transform your problem into a semidefinite program, then finding an SDP solver should be the easy part. Of course, it may be impossible to transform your problem into a semidefinite program.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Thanks, I learned something new - awesome! I wasn't aware of the field of SDP, I mostly studied convex optimization. I will look into it. While SDP methods are optimized for my original problem, I see advantages of my approach, which are that 1) I am able to state that eigenvalues need to be positive, not just non-negative, or alternatively that they should be at least of a certain size (which is also very useful) and 2) I can state that eigenvalues should not be too large as well. So my question remains: Is my approach valid? Will there be practical issues with my approach?

Comment: You can place bounds on eigenvalues using SDP, too. Using the eigendecomposition, every instance of the optimization variable is replaced with a cubic expression, and that looks like a high price to pay.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: I do NOT need to do the eigendecomposition - that is the good part! The solver "tries" different values for $Q$ and $\Lambda$, making sure that the eigenvalues (in $\Lambda$) are as specified with bounds and without having bounds on the varialbes of Q. Then I calculate $\Sigma$ from $Q, \Lambda$ within the definition of the cost function and then the cost. It will be a bit difficult, but I should even be able to calculate the gradient for the elements of $Q$ and $\Lambda$ (I have done something similar before). I don't need to decompose, just to "compose" ;-).

Answer (score 1):

When you do the eigendecomposition of a PSD matrix, $Q$ is an orthonormal matrix (remember that the columns of $Q$ are real and orthonormal eigenvectors of $\Sigma$). This orthonormality condition ties the selection of the columns of $Q$ together and avoids solving each individual column separately. Therefore, $Q$ does not have $n$ independent variables to find with optimization. In more detail, if you fix the first $i-1$ columns of $Q$, you can select any $n-i$ elements of the $i$'th column as free variables. This leaves you with $n(n-1)/2$ free elements in $Q$ and $n$ positive eigenvalues to choose, which is the same as $n(n+1)/2$ independent elements you had before.